# Django REST Framework tutorial sends Page Not Found on part 1

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to Django and API developing, so I started following Django REST Framework tutorial, and I have an error in the first part of it.

When I go to "127.0.0.1:2000/" on my browser, the Api Root page appears (I hosted it on port 2000), so it seems to be working, but when I try to go to "127.0.0.1:2000/snippets/", I get a Page Not Found error.

I imagine this is a very simple thing I'm just overlooking, but I'm kind of stuck right now, and would appreciate the help. Should my "tutorial/urls.py" include the snippets in any way? I followed the tutorial from the beginning, and re-viewed it, so I don't think so, but its a hypothesis.

According to the tutorial, my tutorial\urls.py (tutorial being the project name) looks like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

And the app's (snippets\urls.py) like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('snippets/', views.snippet_list),
    path('snippets/<int:pk>/', views.snippet_detail),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add your URLs from the app you created to the main URLs .py?

Comment: I added the contents of my urls.py to the question now.

Comment: Do you have a views function that renders an html page & an html file in the template folder for the browser to load? ...

Comment: The views generated in the tutorial are meant to be enough. And I solved it now, originally when I asked, I was missing one of the methods in the views.py (snippet_detail). Then I had an error in which I couldn't connect to the server, but then I saw I had a syntax mistke in the tutorial\urls.py, I had an extra line which didn't make sense, and after that, the error was gone and I can now connect to the 127.0.0.1/snippets/ url. Thanks!